# C pointer question (main versus function parameters)

Tags: c, pointers

I am really struggling with pointers in C. Specifically, I have been having trouble understanding how to work with pointers when they are in main versus when I input a pointer into a function parameter from main.

I have a few scenario questions about them that hopefully someone can answer:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int x = 7;
    int* num = 4;
    char* word = "johnny";

    //Q1. how do I get the address of 'num'? 
    //Q2. how do I get the address of 'x'? (should I be using x's or num's address?)
    //Q2. how do I get the value of 'num'?

    //Q3. how do I get the address of 'word'?
    //Q4. how do I get the whole string for 'word'?
    //Q5. how do I get an individual character in 'word'? (for index 0 ('j') and index 3 ('n'))

}


bool some_func (int* count, char** name) {

    //Q6. how do I get the address of the inputted 'count'?
    //Q7. how do I get the value of the inputted 'count'?

    //Q8. how do I get the address of the inputted string 'name'?
    //Q9. how do I get the whole string of the inputted string 'name'?
    //Q10. how do I get an individual character of the inputted string 'name'? (for index 0 ('j') and index 3 ('n'))

}
```

For my recent homework assignments, I've been given intimidating headers like these and I don't know how to get the values that I want out of them. Say I found out that saying '*name' got me the whole string, where do I go from there?

If someone could answer all of the questions in the code I think that would probably be the best way of learning it since it's through example. Thanks!

Comment: `int* num = 4;` is a constraint violation, the compiler should reject the code. If you don't see an error message then please adjust your compiler settings , this will save you time. The other questions about `num` don't make sense until this is fixed

Comment: Thanks, it should be fixed now for people to help.

Comment: The problem is still the same  (whitespace is not significant)

Comment: It should be `int num = 4;`. Then you call the function using `&num` to send a pointer.

Comment: Thanks M.M.  Also  Barmar, I'm just trying to learn. This question is basically 10 quick coding questions in one.

Comment: I understand you're trying to learn. That's what schools, textbooks, and tutorials are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when you declare `int* num`, you created a pointer. You cannot assign a value directly to a pointer. What you could do is declare a variable, like you did for `int x`, and point the pointer to variable `x` (hence the name pointer) by using `num = &x` (&x refers to address of x, and is assigned to num) To get the value of `num`, you will have to use `*num`. Below is an example:

```
int *num;
int a = 4;
num = &a;
printf("address of a is %p, and value of a is %d", num, *num);
```

Output to first example:

```
address of a is <0xsome address> , and value of a is 4
```

As for characters, same thing you can't assign a value directly to pointer (like you did in `char* word = "johnny";`. A concept I think you should know is that `"johnny"` is a String, and strings are essentially an array of characters, hence each character of the string has its own address. Using similar to previous example:

```
char* word;
char someString[6] = "johnny";
word = &someString[0];
printf("address of first char of someString is %p, 1st char of someString is %c, 2nd char of someString is %c", word, *(word), *(word+1));
```

Output for the second example:

address of first char of someString is   <0xsome address>, 1st char of someString is j, 2nd char of someString is o

Importing thing to note is that when accessing each character of the string using de-referencing of pointers, the `+n` must be inside the bracket with the pointer `word`.

`*word+1 //WRONG`

`*(word+1) //CORRECT`

Hope this gives you a base foundation of what you will need to tackle the rest of the questions!

Comment: Thanks that really helped clear things up a bit. I found this site which kind of makes it clear on how the parameter relates to the value. http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Function/Charpointerasthefunctionparameter.htm